# How to properly resolve warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' (without surpressing it)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm getting a lot of CS1998 warnings in my application and I'm looking how to resolve them in my case.

For example I have an IDataService interface that has a method signature `Task<DataModel> GetData()`.

Then I have lets say an implementation of `RealDataService : IDataService` that does some writing/reading of files and since it uses async I/O methods they are called with `await` and the method signature is changed to `async Task<DataModel> GetData()`.

This is then called from the UI with the `var data = await _dataService.GetData();`. All is well up to this point.

But then I have a need test my data and I create another implementation of the data interface `MockupDataService : IDataService` where data is just hardcoded and no async operations are performed. Everything still works as it should, but those pesky CS1998 warnings start to appear when building the application.

There are a lot of solutions to this problem that can be found online:

- Disabling this type of warning
- Using the call of `await Task.Yeild();`
- Using the Task.From result -> `return await Task.FromResult<DataModel>(new DataModel());`
- I think I've seen more, but can't remember them now.

But none of this solutions feel "more right" than other so I would like to know what is the proper way of solving this? I know a lot of people have much deeper knowledge of async programming in C# and will be able to offer some insights/answers on this issue.

Comment: The method inside the mock service doesn't need to be `async`, remove that modifier and do `return Task.FromResult<DataModel>(new DataModel());`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there's no `await`, remove the `async` keyword. `async` doesn't make a method asynchronous. It's not part of the method signature. It's just syntactic sugar that allows the use of `await` to *await* an already executing asynchronous operation without blocking.

In your test method create an already completed task with `Task.FromResult` and return it as-is:

```
public Task<DataModel> GetData()
{
    var model=new DataModel();
    //Add some test data
    return Task.FromResult(model);
}
```

Comment: If you don't have a return type (like a simple `Task`). You can use `Task.CompletedTask`.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the `async` keyword from the method. Then use `return Task.FromResult(...)`

Comment: If your method has no return value you can return a Completed Task

<code>
   public Task Foo()
   {
       // Do something 
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
<code/>